# Beginener to javascript, please help, this doesnt work for some reason

Tags: javascript

I'm very new I dont know what the problem can possibly be. Code

```js
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log("Inside the loop:", i);
    }
    
    console.log("Outside the loop:", i);
```

This is what it prints,

Inside the loop:
Inside the loop:
Inside the loop:
Inside the loop:
Inside the loop:

I am trying to find the difference between let and var, but if you can, I don't really want a too complex sentence, as I probably wont understand, anything.

Comment: Can't reproduce that output.

Comment: OOPS THIS IS THE OUTPUT WROTE THE WRONG THING lmao Inside the loop: 0
Inside the loop: 1
Inside the loop: 2
Inside the loop: 3
Inside the loop: 4 Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined

Answer (score 0):

When you use `let i = 0` inside a for loop, the scope of the variable `i` is limited to only the for loop. You can only use this variable inside there. Outside the for loop, this variable is undefined. If you want to use this variable outside the for loop, you should use `var` instead of `let`.

[EDIT]: It is important to note that it is highly NOT RECOMMENDED and not a good coding practice to use global variables. With that in mind, avoid using `var` whenever it is possible.

Take a look here:
[var keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

And here:
[let keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I also have another question of can you use the var keyword through many like you know scripts. Like in one script you define apple, like var apple = 5; but then can you use the var apple in another script, so you dont have to type it again in the script, or is var only available in that script, also is this true for const? Thanks!

Comment: `var` is global, so it can be declared inside the loop and called outside

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the variable `i` outside of the loop. The way you have it, the variable is only active inside the for loop. You'll need to give it a value as the outside statement requires one.

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("Inside the loop:", i);
}
    
    console.log("Outside the loop:", i);
```

Comment: You don't need to declare `var` outside of the loop, only `const` and `let`. `var` always has global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `var` and `let`/`const` is scope.

If you use `var`, you can declare it inside the loop (inside the for statement) and it will work outside the loop as well. `var` always has global scope:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("Inside the loop:", i);
}

console.log("Outside the loop:", i);
```

If you use `let` inside the for loop, as you see, the statement outside the loop doesn't recognize it. `let` (or `const`) only has local scope (i.e. inside the function, loop, or braces in which it is declared):

```js
let i

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("Inside the loop:", i);
}

console.log("Outside the loop:", i);
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log("Inside the loop: " + i);
}

console.log("Outside the loop:" + i);
```

Comment: Did you mean for the output to be empty?